# Seismic image processing questions on Physics SE

Tags: support, scope

Would I be allowed to post question relating to seismic image processing on Physics SE under the "Geophysics" tag?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard without knowing what you want to do and, indeed, without seeing the question. Depending on its content it may be on topic at DSP, or possibly Computational Science. However, you can always ask  the question here and find out later that it's not a good fit for this site; seeing the question will help us direct you to a better home for it if it isn't. (If you do, of course, link to it here and to this discussion from there.)

Comment: This. There should be no questions on data analysis that are not allowed on *one* of these sites. You ask about the physics here, the programing details on SciComp and about the signal math on DSP. If you are unsure, take your best guess and try it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say anything for sure without seeing the question itself, but probably not. Remember, questions posted on this site have to be about physics. Image processing doesn't really fall under that scope. The tags exist only to *classify* questions, not to tell you which ones are on topic and which ones aren't. (Though a lack of appropriate tags does tend to *suggest* that a question is off topic.)

Sometimes questions of this nature are on topic at [DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), so you could check there.

Comment: It does make [tag:data-analysis] a bit murky though. I agree, without seeing the question it is hard to say but analyzing data isn't entirely off-topic depending on how it's phrased.